# Getting 2d char array from function in c

Tags: c, memory, split, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to split my char string by space and here is my code.(reference to others)

```
void main() {
    char origin_str[] = "How are you";
    int n_segs = Words_counts(origin_str);
    char **split_array = malloc(n_segs * sizeof(char*));
    split_array = split_str_to_array(origin_str);
    ..... //do something
    free(split_array);
}
```

and the split_str_to_array function:

```
char **split_str_to_array(const char strr[]) {
    char **res = NULL;
    char * p = strtok(strr, " ");
    int n_spaces = 0;

    while (p) {
        res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*) * ++n_spaces);
        if (res == NULL)
            exit(-1); 

        res[n_spaces - 1] = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    res = realloc(res, sizeof(char*) * (n_spaces + 1));
    res[n_spaces] = 0;
    return res;
}
```

It works well, butI'm confused with the usage of getting char array from the split_str_to_array function.

Should I use free(res) in the split function?If yes, how do I return the char array? Declaring a new one with known length to return?

I'm afraid of memory using problems in the split function. Or, a better way to do the same?

very appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `free()` is correct.

Free what you allocated if not needed any more, by passing to `free()` what had been returned by the allocating function.

However the allocation in `main()` is useless

```
char **split_array = malloc(n_segs * sizeof(char*));
```

as in the next line

```
split_array = split_str_to_array(origin_str);
```

you overwrite what had been assigend to `split_array`.

Doing so you lose what had been returned by `malloc()` so you cannot free it anymore and with this introduce a memory leak.